# how to run timer function multiple times in parallel in matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, timer, matlab-guide

This is a matlab code that uses guide to run a timer. The timer function counts 10 numbers starting from the number provided in the text field. I would like to know how to enter two numbers successively and make matlab counts 10 numbers for both values in parallel.

let's say I entered 0 then I pressed the start button, then I immediately entered 10 and pressed the start button again. what happens now is that it counts only from 0 to 10. I would appreciate if you can share a way to make my code count from 0 to 10 and from 10 to 20 simultaneously in parallel.

guide code :

```
function startbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

t=timer;
t.TimerFcn = @counter;
t.Period   = 15;
t.ExecutionMode  = 'fixedRate';
t.TasksToExecute = 1;
start(t);
stop (t);
delete (t);
```

timer callback function:

```
function counter(~,~)

handles = guidata(counterFig);
num = str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));


for i = 0:10
    disp (num);
    num = num+1;
    pause (1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use parrallel toolbox for real parallel computation. 
but if you dont have that , you can create another timer object that count from 10 to 20
and run it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have been reading about parallel toolbox but I still don't understand how this can make the timer function runs multiple times in parallel upon clicking the start button. I will very much appreciate it if you can show me some code that will solve this problem.

Comment: Regarding the second option which is creating a second timer object that counts from 10 to 20. I wonder if there is a way where a new timer object can be created each time the button is pressed.